# The type TableSchema.Builder is deprecated

Tags: java, apache-flink

According to the title, the type **TableSchema.Builder** is deprecated and the advise of VScode is that: `This class has been deprecated as part of FLIP-164. It has been replaced by two more dedicated classes **Schema and ResolvedSchema**. Use Schema for declaration in APIs. ResolvedSchema is offered by the framework after resolution and validation.`

My problem : **how to replaced** the tableSchema by two more dedicated classes Schema and **ResolvedSchema**?

By the way, I am searching for a long time on internet. But i could not find anything. Need some ideas how to achieve this, thanks in advance.

```
TableSchema.Builder tableBuilder = new TableSchema.Builder().fields(names, types);
                    primaryKey.ifPresent(
                    pk -> tableBuilder.primaryKey(
                    pk.getName(), pk.getColumns().toArray(new String[0])));
            TableSchema tableSchema = tableBuilder.build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends for what you would like to declare a schema: a catalog table, a connector, a DataStream API conversion?

All locations above offer a `Schema` parameter. As a user, you usually only need to use `Schema`. However, the `Schema.Builder` offers methods to inherit components from a `ResolvedSchema` that comes out of the framework.